# Is this SoundJuicer bug in 12.04, or an OS bug (and where is there a solution)?

Tags: 12.04, gvfs, sound-juicer

When I used SoundJuicer the first time in 12.04, it worked correctly.  When reading the second CD, it failed completely with the message: "SoundJuicer could not read the track listing on this CD.  Reason: Cannot access CD: The specified location is not mounted".

Which is odd, since I am getting there through the GUI file system.

Is this a known bug (but is somehow not searchable using the exact error message, either as  a quoted string, or as the list of tokens)?  Is there some other search term that I should have used?  I'll admit to being a newbie Ubuntu user, but I use RedHat at work, and often have to debug system level events-- those are easy to find via the error string.  Am I wrong to expect otherwise here?  Should I have searched the SoundJuicer site?

I sent a "report" (is that ubuntu-bug?  I can't find that in my process table in the system-monitor-- is it for some reason not listed?), but thought that instead of waiting on an answer, I'd try to find a solution without waiting since there was a (remarkably) similar bug in 11.10.  The core-dump is "helpfully" hidden (and I cannot seem to copy from the report in any case), but I can report that the problem originates in gvfsd-cdda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of SoundJuicer that they won't solve. You have to close SoundJuicer and start it again to make it work.

Excuse me if I don't post a link to back my information, but I struggled with this for a long time. Now I just restart it after inserting a new CD.

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm the CD you inserted have no problem? Isn't the CD corrupted? If this problem happens randomly, check whether your CD-ROM drive works properly, or try to clean the drive. If you are frequent CD/DVD drive user, pick-up part of CD-ROM drive may be wasted down.

Comment: Drive reads correctly in file-system (displays correct number of tracks), and vlc totem.  But totem fails to connect w/CD-ID databases, and doesn't save without much extra programming.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm having the same issues with sound-juicer with a CD that even (after a lot of failed attempts) was readable in Rhythmbox. Brand new CD btw :)

Comment: I solved my Rhythmbox problems by deleting ~/.gstreamer-0.10

Comment: Rhythmbox reads fine.  But it says to use SoundJuicer for importing a CD, so I'm stuck (without writing my own version of SoundJuicer, which seems silly since it was working so well for so long (before 11.04).